# Crafter CMS 3.0 - is it possible in crafter-cms to preview just the content page

Tags: crafter-cms

I need a a way in Crafter studio to preview that page being designed without showing the studio header from it's own URL. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What runs on port 8080 includes Crafter Engine in Preview mode (no caching). So simply point the browser to `localhost:8080?crafterSite=YOURSITE` where `YOURSITE` the site ID.

If you don't use `crafterSite`, it will try to guess the site based on the authoring cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to open the page as normal with the Studio header then go to http://localhost:8080/yourPage either in a new tab or the same one.